# Cannot connect to MS access Database from Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, iis-7, setup-deployment, ms-access-2010

I have built a Webservice(*.asmx) to connect to MS Access residin in App_Data folder.
It works fine whenever I try to connect and do any operations. But when I deployed the app on IIS, I cannot even connect to MS access. Can some one please guide why this is happening?
I have given full persmissions to IIS_users and othet users too. I tried to copy the database to different folder and access but could not. Also tried to change the application pool, but this too failed.
In my connectionstring , I tried all combinations but still could not.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Comment: What does you connection string look like ? What objects are you using to connect to the database? Are you getting an exception back ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be ridiculous. The issue was with Applicationpool. Setting the application pools "Enable 32 bit applications" =TRUE enabled to connect MS ACCESS.